# Mapping through the list and replacing values

Tags: python, list, replace

I have two lists. List one is

```
lst1 = ["select Who.ID,Owner.Name,ActivityDate,Type FROM TASK Where Status='Completed' AND ActivityDate = 2014-04-23 AND Owner.Name = OWNERNAME", 
"select Who.ID,Owner.Name,ActivityDate,Type FROM TASK Where Status='Completed' AND ActivityDate = 2014-04-22 AND Owner.Name = OWNERNAME", 
"select Who.ID,Owner.Name,ActivityDate,Type FROM TASK Where Status='Completed' AND ActivityDate = 2014-04-21 AND Owner.Name = OWNERNAME"]
```

List two is :

```
lst2 = ['Kyle', 'Jen', 'Batman']
```

I want to replace the OWNERNAME pointer in lst1 with each item in lst2. So I would have a list of 3*3=9 elements. I am trying to use the map function:

```
def replName(string,lst2=['Kyle', 'Jen', 'Batman']):
    for item in lst2:
        string = string.replace('OWNERNAME', item)

finallst = map(replName, lst1)
```

It does not work. Help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can create the list with a list comprehension:

```
res = [row.replace("OWNERNAME", name) for name in lst2 for row in lst1 ]
```

Answer (score -1):

Presuming `lst1` is a list of actual strings and  to keep the order:

```
final = []

for ind, ele in enumerate(lst1):
    final += [ele.replace("OWNERNAME",x) for x in lst2]
print final

["'select Who.ID,Owner.Name,ActivityDate,Type FROM TASK Where Status='Completed' AND ActivityDate = 2014-04-23 AND Owner.Name = Kyle", "'select Who.ID,Owner.Name,ActivityDate,Type FROM TASK Where Status='Completed' AND ActivityDate = 2014-04-23 AND Owner.Name = Jen", "'select Who.ID,Owner.Name,ActivityDate,Type FROM TASK Where Status='Completed' AND ActivityDate = 2014-04-23 AND Owner.Name = Batman", '"select Who.ID,Owner.Name,ActivityDate,Type FROM TASK Where Status="Completed" AND ActivityDate = 2014-04-22 AND Owner.Name = Kyle"', '"select Who.ID,Owner.Name,ActivityDate,Type FROM TASK Where Status="Completed" AND ActivityDate = 2014-04-22 AND Owner.Name = Jen"', '"select Who.ID,Owner.Name,ActivityDate,Type FROM TASK Where Status="Completed" AND ActivityDate = 2014-04-22 AND Owner.Name = Batman"', '"select Who.ID,Owner.Name,ActivityDate,Type FROM TASK Where Status="Completed" AND ActivityDate = 2014-04-21 AND Owner.Name = Kyle"', '"select Who.ID,Owner.Name,ActivityDate,Type FROM TASK Where Status="Completed" AND ActivityDate = 2014-04-21 AND Owner.Name = Jen"', '"select Who.ID,Owner.Name,ActivityDate,Type FROM TASK Where Status="Completed" AND ActivityDate = 2014-04-21 AND Owner.Name = Batman"']
```

A list comp that keeps the order:

```
[ele.replace("OWNERNAME", x)for ele in lst1 for x in lst2  ]
```

`ind` is the index of each element looping through `lst1`, so we replace "OWNERNAME" with the names  from `lst2`

As posted the syntax in  `lst1` is not actually valid.

Comment: This creates only 3 of the 9 possible varations

Comment: I only noticed the 9, not exaclty hard to make it a list of nine entries.